# Can't create bulk report for YouTube Content Owner Estimated Revenue Report? Permission Denied? Scopes All Approved

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to pull this report from the YouTube Analytics API: `content_owner_estimated_revenue_a1`

But I am getting the following error:

```py
'error': {'code': 403, 'message': 'The caller does not have permission', 'status': 'PERMISSION_DENIED'}
```

These are the approved scopes I currently have in the credentials of my request (In the code example below, self.token /  is an access token generated from OAuthing a Google user / brand account):

```py
"scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]
```

What am I missing?

I tried to make the request to generate the bulk report. I got the error given above.

Here's a quick extract of my Python class:

```py
    response = self.session.request(
        method='POST',
        url='https://youtubereporting.googleapis.com/v1/jobs',
        headers={
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.token,
        },
        json={
            'reportTypeId': 'content_owner_estimated_revenue_a1',
            'name': 'content_owner_estimated_revenue_a1',
        },
    )
```

OR

```bash
curl -X POST \
  https://youtubereporting.googleapis.com/v1/jobs \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "reportTypeId": "content_owner_estimated_revenue_a1",
    "name": "content_owner_estimated_revenue_a1"
  }'
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your code

Comment: Hi @LindaLawton-DaImTo, code included now :)

Comment: where is self.token comming from

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo that's just the access token for the user / brand account.

We have these scopes: 

'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',

Comment: well the error message says the user who created that access token dosent have access

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo yep very aware that's what the message says.  I am trying to understand why the token does not have access, since all scopes in the docs are granted with that token & other reports create fine.

Comment: its not the token its the user that logged in that doesn't have access.   If I create qn access token I can't access your data either as I don't have permission Find a user with access and have them run your app and create a valid access token